# How to access an instance variable from a separate controller(amount variable in checkout)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, stripe-payments

I am working on the checkout process of my tool rental app project using Stripe checkout. I am running into a problem when I want to dynamically change the rent-price dependent on what the person who posts the tool wants to rent it at.

I have my charges nested within my tools like so:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  root 'pages#home'

  resources :tools do
    resources :charges
    get :manage, :on => :collection
  end
```

When I navigate to /tools/1/charges/new I am getting the following error:

```
Couldn't find Tool with 'id'=
```

This is my charges controller:

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController

    def new
      @tool = Tool.find(params[:id])
      @amount = @tool.rent_price * 100
    end

    def create
      @tool = Tool.find(params[:id])
      @amount = @tool.rent_price * 100

      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        :email => 'example@stripe.com',
        :card  => params[:stripeToken]
      )

      charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        :customer    => customer.id,
        :amount      => @amount,
        :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
        :currency    => 'usd'
      )

    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      flash[:error] = e.message
      redirect_to charges_path
    end

    private

    def tool_params
        params.require(:tool).permit(:name, :description, :user_id, :tool_image, :rent_price)
    end

end
```

This is my tools controller:

```
class ToolsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_tool, only:[:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_action :authenticate_user!, only:[:new, :destroy, :edit, :manage], notice: 'you must be logged in to proceed'

    def index
        @tools = Tool.all
    end

    def manage
        @user = current_user 
        @tools = @user.tools
    end

    def show
    end

    def new
        @tool = Tool.new 
    end

    def create
        @tool = Tool.new(tool_params)
        if @tool.save
            redirect_to @tool
        else
            redirect_to :action => "new"
            flash[:notice] = "You did not fill out all the fields"
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
        @tool.update(tool_params)
        redirect_to @tool
    end

    def destroy
        @tool.destroy
        redirect_to tools_path
    end

    private

    def set_tool
        @tool = Tool.find(params[:id])
    end

    def tool_params
        params.require(:tool).permit(:name, :description, :user_id, :tool_image, :rent_price)
    end

end
```

Take a look at my charges controller. The Stripe checkout documentation usually has the amount value hardcoded into the @amount instance variable. However I want it to be set by the tool creator. I have a rent_price column on my tool table and want to pass this value to the amount instance variable.

I attempt to do it by finding the tool under which the charge is being created. However there is no Charge Model and hence no association between the Tool and Charge. Stripe checkout works without the model. I am not sure how to access the amount set by the tool creator(Tool.rent_price) in the charges controller in this case. It appears there is no Tool.id being passed to the param. Any ideas on how to fix this?

I am thinking i will create a charges model even though stripe doesnt say to and use an association to chain call the amount. But not sure if there is a better way without having to create the charges model.

Comment: You can use `rake routes` to check what routes exist and what arguments they take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me it looks like problem with using wrong parameters or problem with routes.

Did you try using `Tool.find(params[:tool_id])` instead of `Tool.find(params[:id])`?

According to documentation about nested resources http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources, in your example, `params[:id]` should be related to charge resource and `params[:tool_id]` to tool resource.

Comment: This was correct! I'm still getting used to alot of these things, thanks!